# Could Clojure's STM model be made to work over multiple JVMs?

Tags: clojure

I know that Clojure works well on a multicore machine, but I was wondering if it would make sense for it to work over a JVM cluster spread out over many machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Runa](http://www.runa.com/) looked into using Terracotta for this and ended up publishing [swarmiji](https://github.com/amitrathore/swarmiji) as a distributed agent library.

One of the real differences between an SMP system and a Cluster is shared memory. In a Cluster, code has to ask for data, whereas in SMP it can just read it directly. This has some nice advantages and some (scaling) disadvantages.

Clojure's STM, which differes quite significantly from the many other STM systems out there, is built upon the notion of **relative time** as measured by a generation counter per transaction. Without common access to this generation counter it cannot give events an order and can't do it's job (please forgive this overly simple explanation).

One of the STM's main motivations was to create a system that really took advantage of **shared memory concurrency** by ensuring, for instance, that readers never wait for writers and readers always see valid data. Because this was build to take advantage of shared memory it loses a lot of its appeal without shared memory.

The actor model (ala Erlang) is a better fit for distributed computing.

Or, in other words: perhaps we should not try to put a square peg in a distributed concurrent hole.

Answer (score 5):

Not really. I mean, it *could* be made to work; things like Terracotta claim to be able to distribute a logical JVM over multiple nodes, but clojure's STM / collection semantics rely pretty strongly on inter-thread memory sharing to be efficient wrt space and time.

You're probably better off taking care of the multi-node parts of your system using a message-passing or batch-oriented architecture.

Comment: There was work done by Paul Stadig at one point to make it possible to distribute Clojure data structures over Terracotta (several bug fixes went into both projects as a result).  But that is a far cry from actually supporting distributed STM.

Answer (score 3):

I could do it but its not a good idea. There is a reason that NoSql is big now, its because transaction don't work well ofer a network.

Answer (score 1):

The Avout project allows you to distribute STM state over multiple machines:

- http://avout.io/
- https://github.com/liebke/avout